# How can you keep rotated draggable objects inside the Raphael paper?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have an application with many draggable objects that can also be rotated in 90 degree increments.  I'm trying to figure out how to stop the user from dragging the objects outside the Raphael paper (canvas).

This is fairly simple for unrotated objects.  I can simply see if the current x and y coordinates are less than 0 and set them to 0 instead.  I can adjust similarly by checking if they are outside the canvas width and height.

However, a problem arises when the object is rotated because for some odd reason the coordinate plane rotates as well. Is there an easy way to keep objects inside the canvas?  Or is there an example of some this somewhere?

I have spent many hours fiddling with this and I can't seem to make sense of the rotated coordinate plane in order to adjust my calculations.  Even when debugging the current coordinates, they seem to shift oddly if I drag an object, release it, and then drag the object again.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I needed to move a shape within the boundaries of another shape, so what I did was:

```
element.drag(onstart, onmove, onend);

...
onStart: function(x,y,e){
        //  Initialize values so it doesn't recalculate per iteration
        // this allows to resume dragging from the point it were left
        App.oldX = 0;
        App.oldY = 0;
        App.currentCircleX  = App.fingerPath.attr('cx');
        App.currentCircleY  = App.fingerPath.attr('cy');
    },
    onMove: function(dx,dy,x,y,e){
        App.setDirection(dx,dy);
    },
    onEnd: function(e){
        // nothing to do here for now
    },

// this function tells the element to move only if it's within the bound area
    setDirection: function(dx, dy){
        var isXYinside;
        this.newX   = this.currentCircleX - (this.oldX - dx);
        this.newY   = this.currentCircleY - (this.oldY - dy);

        // HERE is the key, this method receives your bounding path and evaluates the positions given and then returns true or false
        isXYinside  = Raphael.isPointInsidePath(this.viewportPath, this.newX, this.newY);
        this.oldX   = dx;
        this.oldY   = dy;
        // so if it is within the bound area, will move, otherwise will just stay there
        if (isXYinside) {
            this.fingerPath.attr({
                "cx": this.newX,
                "cy": this.newY
            });
            this.currentCircleX = this.newX;
            this.currentCircleY = this.newY;
        }
    }
```

I know this is an old one, but I stumbled upon this question when trying to figure out a way to do it. So here's my 2 cents in case someone has this problem.

Reference:

[Raphael.isPointInsidePath](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.isPointInsidePath)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Element.getBBox()
There Are 2 flavones which give the result before rotation and after rotation 
You should toggle the Boolean argument and test it

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The x and y from `getBBox()` do stay correct, even when the image is rotated.  The `attrs` x and y do not.  However, this still leaves me with the problem of stopping the object going out of bounds.  I can now correctly check it's location with `getBBox()`, but I don't know how to set the `attrs` x and y to the edge value.

Comment: You can use Element.translate(x,y); to move it

Comment: Unable to get Ur question correctly. Please put a fiddle so that it could be helpful in understanding your question